# command line arguments not working on visual c++ express 2010

Tags: c, visual-c++, command-line-arguments

I am having an issue passing command line arguments to my program using Visual C++ Express 2010. I found the command arguments under debugging and using the following input, just the terms with white space between them. The file is in my project folder with the .c source code.

**TestFile1.txt 2**

The program works fine when I just statically define the char pointer under main. So at this point I'm not sure if the issue is with 2010 or the code. I haven't figured out a way to compile and execute in some other way to test command line args. It would be great if someone could compile this an see if it works on their system.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    #define BUFFER_SIZE 256

    int main(char *argv[])
    {
       //char *argv[] = { "program", "TestFile1.txt", "2" };
       char buf[BUFFER_SIZE];
       FILE *inFp;

       printf("%s",argv[1]);
       if ((inFp = fopen (argv[1], "r")) == NULL)
       {
          fprintf(stderr, "Can't open file\n");
          exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
       }

       fclose(inFp);
       return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

it should be `int main(int argc, char *argv[])` Other than that, I have not seen any other problem with your program.

Comment: I understand that that `int main(int argc, char *argv[])` is the typical way to do this, but I don't care about the count. I know the first argument is argv[1] and the second is argv[2]. I should be able to just get them that way as far as I know.

Comment: @jordan what issue are you facing?

Comment: @jordan, no:  the first argument will be an int whether you like it or not.  With your `main` argument list it will try to interpret that int as a pointer to a char.

Comment: The program builds fine, but when I try debugging, it crashes.        Unhandled exception at 0x010d13fd in MyPrograms.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000007.   CXX0030: Error: expression cannot be evaluated

Comment: @jordan that is because you're trying to access the memory location "3" which is, on your system, not allowed. I bet its the SIGSEGV fault or the 0xC00000005 fault?

Comment: Works ok with the int argc. I just don't like the idea of having an unused formal parameter hanging around.

Comment: you can suppress it, or just say argc=argc

Comment: Upvoting and Accepting an answer is Stack Overflow's way of saying "Thanks" :-) @jordan